# -bash: append_path: command not found when open tmux

Tags: bash, tmux

When I open the tmux, the following errors are shown inside tmux

```
-bash: append_path: command not found
-bash: append_path: command not found
-bash: append_path: command not found
~/ $
```

Setup:

- tmux 3.1b
- 5.8.11-1-MANJARO

I have noticed that the `append_path` is defined in `/etc/profile`

So, why tmux is not finding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Manjaro is an Arch Linux derivative, I'm guessing this is the problem - adding the `set-option` in `.tmux.conf` only half-solved it for me - the message still appeared right after a successful login:

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/j0zly6/bash_append_path_command_not_found/

So what you need to do is to is (as root):

```
mv /etc/profile{,.old}
mv /etc/profile{.pacnew,}
```

If you've modified the old `/etc/profile.old` you need to manually merge them.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar issue [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/j4hr9c/i_switched_from_bash_to_zsh_im_using_tmux_and_now/).

So, what you have to do is insert the the command

```
set-option -g default-command '/bin/bash'`
```

in your `~/.tmux.conf`.